# prove that $\int(f(x)+g(x))dx= \int f(x)dx+\int g(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Let $f,g$ be two functions defined on $A$. Supposed that $F$ and $G$ are anti-derivative of $f$ and $ g$. Prove that

$\int(f(x)+g(x))dx= \int f(x)dx + \int g(x)dx$

Here is what I got.

Let $H(x)$ be a function such that $H'(x)=f(x)+g(x)$

Since $F$ and $G$ are anti-derivative of $f$ and $ g$

$F'(x)=f(x)$ and $G'(x)=g(x)$

so $H'(x)=f(x)+g(x)=F'(x)+G'(x)=(F(x)+ G(x))'$

thus $H(x)= F(x)+G(x)+C$

what do I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof has all the right pieces, but is not laid out in the usual order.

1. $F,G$ are anti-derivatives of $f$, $g$.
2. Let's define $H(x)=F(x)+G(x)$.
3. Calculate $H'(x)$, and (using properties of derivatives), see that $H'(x)=F'(x)+G'(x)=f(x)+g(x)$.
4. Hence, $\int f(x)+g(x)dx =H(x)$.
5. Consequently, $f(x)+g(x)$ is integrable, with integral $H(x)$.
6. Further, $\int f(x)+g(x)dx=H(x)=F(x)+G(x)=\int f(x)dx + \int g(x)dx$, as desired.